# Raffle after50 donates

Tags: php, mysql

I want make raffle always after 50 donates.
I try this (because all information about donates I have in DB)

```
<?php

$percent = round(min(100*($sum/$goal),100));

$test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dc_comments WHERE message='GTA' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");


if ($percent > "50") {
    echo $test;
}
?>
```

$percent - how much percent is acquired 
goal e.g 50$

After beyound the goal I would like to automatically chose one random person from a database which is inscribed the message e.g GTA
It would be nice if it was repetitive. eg removed the data from the last draw and chose from among the new persons.
How can I do it?

Comment: Please be aware that PHP's `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated and not recommended for use. You should use the `mysqli_xxx()` functions instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it would be to store the raffle winners in a separate table. That way you can still use your query, but adding a NOT IN condition for the previous raffle winners.

So what do you need to change to the current code?
- Create a new table `raffle_winners`
- Change your query to the following:

```
$test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dc_comments WHERE message='GTA' AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM raffle_winners) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

After each raffle, insert the raffle winner int the `raffle_winners` table.

Comment: But if I want now make raffle after this 50 donates (not repetitive) what I should change in this code?

Comment: Updated my answer. I am not sure how I could explain more extensive.

Comment: I get it - Resource id #7

Comment: Ok, mark my answer as the solution if it helped you :-)